# How to capture stdout / stderr when using multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, python-2.7, io, multiprocessing, subprocess

I'm trying to emulate the `subprocess.Popen stdout / stderr` for Python methods targets, meaning, I want to create N parallel jobs, with unique stdout / stderr handlers.

This is my current code:

```
#!/bin/python
import time
import multiprocessing as mp


class Job(object):
    def __init__(self, target, *a, **kw):
        self.target = target
        self.args = a
        self.kwargs = kw

def parallelize(jobs):
    """
    Args:
        jobs (list): list of the jobs to run. with all its params
    """
    procs = [mp.Process(target=job.target, args=job.args, kwargs=job.kwargs) for job in jobs]
    for p in procs:
        p.start()
    for p in procs:
        p.join()


def dummy(*a, **kw):
    print a
    time.sleep(1)
    print kw


def main():
    parallelize([Job(dummy) for i in range(2)])

main()
```

which only parallelizes jobs. The output is still shown on the screen. If I would have used `subprocess.Popen()` I could have added `stdout=PIPE()` argument for each process creation and store its value in an object, later to be returned from `parallelize()`, but I don't see how.

[multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) gives some options, such as using `conn`, but that does not help because I'm running black box methods, and I can't override them and make themn print send to `conn` instead print.

[This](https://ryanjoneil.github.io/posts/2014-02-14-capturing-stdout-in-a-python-child-process.html) page suggests capturing the stdout, but I think its not good, because parallel processes would output to the same place, without separation ability...

How can I achieve parallel processes (with Python methods targets) with IO control?

*I though of something like `subprocess.Popen('python -c "import my_module; my_module.my_method()", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` but I think it is too hacky.*

Comment: Can you give a shot to `joblib` with `multiprocessing` backend? I believe it captures stdout / stderr.

Comment: @ClsForCookies, did you ever find a solution for this? I am searching for the same thing, though I am specifically trying to redirect stdout from processes using multiprocessing.Pool.

Comment: @strotter, I can't recall. Reading my question now, I'm unsure why the link I posted didn't work for me. Have you tried it?

Comment: @CIsForCookies I, too, need to direct stdout to a unique location per process, rather than all to the same place.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the call to the job target in the [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) context manager (and [`contextlib.redirect_stderr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stderr) for standard error) to capture its standard output in its own way:

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

class Job(object):
    def __init__(self, target, number, *a, **kw):
        self.target = target
        self.number = number
        self.args = a
        self.kwargs = kw

    def run(self):
        with open(f'output_{self.number}.log', 'w') as file, redirect_stdout(file):
            return self.target(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

def parallelize(jobs):
    procs = [mp.Process(target=job.run) for job in jobs]
    for p in procs:
        p.start()
    for p in procs:
        p.join()

def dummy(*a, **kw):
    print(a)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(kw)

def main():
    parallelize([Job(dummy, i, f'foo{i}', bar=i) for i in range(2)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This would produce the following two files:

```
# output_0.log
('foo0',)
{'bar': 0}
```

and:

```
# output_1.log
('foo1',)
{'bar': 1}
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/ExpertAwesomeArray